# API - HttpResponseMessage: (407) proxy authentication required

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, proxy

**Edit 1: Other Controller**

```
public class identityController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> getfullname(string firstName)
        {
            string name = firstName;
            return Ok(name);
        }
    }
```

I have created a controller which uses an API from another solution.
Method that i use in the controller looks like below:

```
public class GetNameController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpGet]

        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> CalculatePrice(string firstName)
        {
            string _apiUrl = String.Format("api/identity/getfullname?firstName={0}", firstName);
            string _baseAddress = "http://testApp.azurewebsites.net/";

            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(_baseAddress);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(_apiUrl);

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    return Ok(response);
                }
            }
            return NotFound();
        }
```

The result of `response.IsSuccessStatusCode` is always `false`. When i check the `response` values i see this result:

```
 {
    StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
    {
      Connection: close
      Date: Thu, 21 Jul 2016 12:28:21 GMT
      Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
      Content-Length: 334
      Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
    }
}
```

What could i be missing?

Comment: you need to put the second controllers code up, please.

Comment: @gh9 which second controller?

Comment: you said you had 2 controllers, controller A which calles controller B. Can you put up controller B's code the one that sites at "http://testApp.azurewebsites.net/api/identity/getfullname?firstName={0}

Comment: @gh9 that controller is in a completely saperate solution, so i can not put it there.

Comment: you can cut and paste any code in regardless of the solution it is in. If we dont see the code we dont know if you are requiring authentication/have the correct call in place/have the correct controller name/ messed with the route some how. We need to see the second controller

Comment: @gh9 i added it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 string _apiUrl = String.Format("api/identity/{0}", firstName);
```

This is assuming that your url is correct, and your testapp is up and running. Even though when I hit it azure tells me your app is stopped. You will need to get your app started first, then change the string _apiUrl to the suggestion above.

http://testapp.azurewebsites.net/api/identity/getfullname?firstName=steve

Gives me this message

> Error 403 - This web app is stopped.
>
> The web app you have attempted to reach is currently stopped and does
>   not accept any requests. Please try to reload the page or visit it
>   again soon.
>
> If you are the web app administrator, please find the common 403 error
>   scenarios and resolution here. For further troubleshooting tools and
>   recommendations, please visit Azure Portal.

So there are several things in your `identity` controller that are going on.

1. the functions name is `getFullName`. Since the word `get` is in the name of the function. Any `httpget` request will be routed to the function automagically. Thus making the `[HttpGet]` redundant. This only works if there is ***1*** and only ***1*** `httpget` request in your controller. If there are multiple you will need to fully qualify the url like you have done
2. Since youa re using the `[httpget]` method attribute I can assume you are using ***webapi2***. That being the case and you are using a
   primitive in your controller argument you can do notneed to fully
   qualify the parameter name on your call. `?firstname={0}` changes to
   `/{0}`

Comment: Thanks, @gh9 i fixed it because i did not know that i need to actually start it. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @eg16 no probs glad I could help